# jQuery DatePicker not Loading

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a piece of jQuery that will not load at all for some reason. I am wondering if it is an error in my syntax or if I am missing something crucial for it to work. This is placed on a page that is included.

```
<script>
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
<div class="demo">

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
<?php echo "hello world againagain!"; ?>
</div>
```

This is in the header of index.php:
/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="Stylesheet" />

```
<script src="<?php echo $intranetName; ?>/js/jquery_1_6.js" type="text/javascript"></script>     
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $intranetName; ?>/js/jquery-ui-   1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
```

The intranetName loads the domain of the scripts. It does load the scripts and shows the correct path in the html source so I do not think that is the issue.  However, I am still a novice to jQuery. Help please! Thanks.

I figured it out. It was due to my copy of jQuery being corrupted. Thank you everyone!

Comment: As a side note, I use a datepicker I found and liked that didn't work with any version higher than 1.4.4 of jQuery, so that may be the issue.

Comment: I would love to show a demo, however this is an Intranet website and can't due to company policy. It is quite frustrating that I am struggling over something small as this haha.

Comment: You Know What I figured it out. I think my copy of Jquery somehow became corrupted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Include `JQuery` before `JQuery-UI`

```
<script src="<?php echo $intranetName; ?>/js/jquery_1_6.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $intranetName; ?>/js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
```

EDIT:

This is working fine on my local machine (i.e. showing datepicker without css):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
<div class="demo">

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

So it must be a problem with your UI package.

Comment: Sorry, I will edit that. It is before the UI. I just pasted it in reverse.

Comment: Vikk you are half right. It was actually my jQuery script itself. Weird, must have been a subversion bug.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Ah you are right, That should be the syntax. I did change it like that, however it still does not load. Any reasons why?

Comment: there are maybe some other reasons like javascript errors and reverse the includes of your javascripts first jquery then the jquery ui...

Comment: Sorry, I pasted them line by line. It is actually in reverse in the script. Do I possibly have to load the css after the script includes?

Comment: I figured it out. It was due to my copy of jQuery being corrupted. Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1):

You're using a customized version of jQuery (**1.8.16.custom.min.js**).

Make sure you're including the *Datepicker* widget in your customized version of the JavaScript file.

Keep in mind that *Datepicker* is inside *Widget* group: http://jqueryui.com/download

Comment: I downloaded Datepicker only, thats why it says it is customized.