# jquery datepicker not working ,date box not appearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, input, datepicker

i am trying to add jquery dtepciker to my application in Grails(Intelli J) but its not showing the datepicker

here is my html code

```
           <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker" style="width:275px"       value="enter date">
```

here is my javascript code

```
                    $(document).ready(function(){

                   $("#datepicker").datepicker();
                    });t
```

but when i click on the text box : datepicker  nothing happens ,  i am new to jquery/ jaa script if you could tell me where i'm wrong ,  do i need to have the jquery datepicker plugin in my application and if yes , how to install that

Also when i mouseover this  .datepicker();   it says  "unresolved function or method datepicker()"

Thank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you need to have jquery and jquery-ui datepicker plugin to make this work. You can download the plugin from http://jqueryui.com/download

Download the js and include in your page.

One more thing, `$("datepicker").datepicker();` should be `$("#datepicker").datepicker();`

Also check out [jQuery DatePicker not Loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012312/jquery-datepicker-not-loading/8012445), it might help.

Comment: thanks , i changed it to $("#datepicker").datepicker();          and added the jquery and jquery-ui plugin (now showing in plugin manager) alse the error "unresolved function or method datepicker()" is gone now but still when i click on the input field nothing happens ...

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
```