# datepicker() unresolved function or method

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

Well, I know this question has been asked before a few times but I'm just a beginner and still couldn't solve it.

I want to set the minimum date of the input date picker to today. In many answers I found the datepicker() method but my webstorm doesn't know this method.

my code:

```
 $("#date").datepicker("option","minDate", new Date(2020,6,5) );
```

Any tipps for me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: `datepicker` is a plugin method, not a core method.  Did you include the plugin?

Comment: Whether or not webstorm recognize the method is not important. Does your code work when you run it in the browser.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8025770/jquery-datepicker-not-working-date-box-not-appearing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery UI " $("#datepicker").datepicker is not a function"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212696/jquery-ui-datepicker-datepicker-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without thinking much about it, it's most likely because you didn't include jQuery UI. `datepicker()` is a jQuery UI only method.

https://jqueryui.com/

Comment: that was it, thanks a lot and sorry for my stupid question

Comment: `.datepicker()` doesn't imply that's it's jquery-ui.  There is one in jquery-ui but there are also 100s of others.

Comment: Question was tagged, `jQuery`.